# MapChart with "countries/us/us-all"

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I can't bind the high map us all countries.

I am having error in data series, below is my map configuration.

importing files

```
import { MapChart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import * as usJson from 'src/assets/maps/us-all.geo.json';
```

map configuration

```
new MapChart({
            chart: {
                map: usJson
            },
            title: {
                text: "Highmaps basic demo"
            },
            subtitle: {
                text:
                    'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js">World, Miller projection, medium resolution</a>'
            },
            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    alignTo: "spacingBox"
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            colorAxis: {
                min: 0
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'mappoint',
                    mapData: usJson,
                    name: 'Cities',
                    data: [
                        {
                            "value": 438,
                            "code": "nj"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": 387.35,
                            "code": "ri"
                        }
                    ]
                }],

        });
    }

}
```

Also added `highmaps` module in app module file.

*here is all series data link.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/us-population-density.json

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor that I could work on? You can start from this template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-map

Comment: Yes, will make a demo and share here.

i have refereed highcharts maps but it's not working for me.